# Use regular expressions to select valid email address

Tags: regex, validation

I came up with the following

```
([\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})
```

I would also like to remove emails that start with a number or -. By remove I mean to select only the address and not to remove the entire match.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: So that we know this isn't a duplicate, could you edit your question to clearly show which types of email addresses are valid and which are not?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Addresses starting with numbers are valid. I just created one with my convenient web application that allows users to easily create mail aliases: `650-039-8799@kylheku.com`.  Please read the relevant RFC's, starting with 822, about what is valid e-mail syntax. About the only RFC feature you might think about rejecting is the use of comments. (Yes, e-mail addresses can contain comments, which is text enclosed in parentheses!)

Answer (score 0):

`^(?:\d+|-+)?([\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})$`

This should do the trick. It'll capture emails but also filter out ones that start with a number or the `-` character and pulls the email from it.

Comment: This will not match quite a few of the existing TLDs (like .weatherchannel, or .americanexpress) nor any internationalised TLD.

Comment: Hey, first of all, thanks a lot. This will not work for me if I'll get an email like this 5644-865hadarikt@gmail.com or even like this 5644-865-765hadarikt@gmail.com. how can I make it to not select that initial sequence? Thanks